# mysql error while trying to create a table with field

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error while trying to create a table in a database..

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, `call_code_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `result_code` ENUM NOT NULL,' at line 1
```

What am I doing wront for this to give me an error?
This is my mysql code.

```
CREATE TABLE  `phone_calls` (

`phone_call_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`account_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`team_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`campaign_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`call_code` ENUM NOT NULL ,
`call_code_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`result_code` ENUM NOT NULL ,
`result_code_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`time_zone_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`trigger_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`first_attempt_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`first_attempt_by` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`first_attempt_by_name` CHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`call_subject` CHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`status` TINYINT( 2 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  '0= purge, 1=active, 2 = in progress, 3 = completed',
`last_attempt_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`last_attempt_by` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`last_attempt_by_name` CHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`total_attempts` TINYINT( 3 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
`modified_by` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`modified_by_name` CHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`client_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`last_call_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`call_direction` ENUM NOT NULL COMMENT  'INBOUND or OUTBOUND',
`call_notes` TEXT NOT NULL ,
INDEX (  `account_id` ,  `team_id` ,  `campaign_id` ,  `call_code` ,  `call_code_id` ,  `result_code` ,  `result_code_id` ,  `time_zone_id` ,  `first_attempt_by` ,  `last_attempt_by` ,  `modified_by` ,  `client_id` ,  `last_call_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: And what should empty ENUM mean? You forgot to specify the enumeration itself, as shown [in this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the possible values for every `enum` column, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  `phone_calls` (
`phone_call_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`account_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`team_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`campaign_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`call_code` ENUM('foo','bar') NOT NULL ,
`call_code_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`result_code` ENUM('foo','bar') NOT NULL ,
`result_code_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`time_zone_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`trigger_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`first_attempt_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`first_attempt_by` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`first_attempt_by_name` CHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`call_subject` CHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`status` TINYINT( 2 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  '0= purge, 1=active, 2 = in progress, 3 = completed',
`last_attempt_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`last_attempt_by` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`last_attempt_by_name` CHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`total_attempts` TINYINT( 3 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
`modified_by` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`modified_by_name` CHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`client_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`last_call_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`call_direction` ENUM('foo','bar') NOT NULL COMMENT  'INBOUND or OUTBOUND',
`call_notes` TEXT NOT NULL ,
INDEX (`account_id` ,  `team_id` ,  `campaign_id` ,  `call_code` ,  `call_code_id` , `result_code` ,  `result_code_id` ,  `time_zone_id` ,  `first_attempt_by` ,  `last_attempt_by` ,  `modified_by` ,  `client_id` ,  `last_call_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for ENUM is incorrect, check this:

[Documention](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

I'm sure you can find your answer there :)